# CString::Replace not working with values from registry

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to implement something where I need to change values in the registry where what I'm removing and what I'm adding is only decided at run time.
my test code:

```
CString test_string, change_from, change_to;
test_string.Format(_T("Communications Port (COM1)"));
change_from.Format(_T("COM1"));
change_to.Format(_T("COM2"));
test_string.Replace(change_from, change_to);
MessageBox(test_string, _T("Test"), MB_OK);
```

works as expected.

but when test_string and change_from are populated from the registry it does not.

```
CRegKey serenum_key;
serenum_key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("System\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\Serenum\\Enum"), KEY_READ);
CRegKey sysenum_key;
sysenum_key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum"), KEY_READ);
DWORD count = 0;
serenum_key.QueryDWORDValue(_T("Count"), count);

CString keyname, keypath, friendlyname, portname;
const ULONG max_len = 256;
ULONG len;
keypath.Preallocate(max_len);
friendlyname.Preallocate(max_len);
portname.Preallocate(max_len);
for (DWORD i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    keyname.Format(_T("%d"), i);
    len = max_len;
    serenum_key.QueryStringValue(keyname, keypath.GetBuffer(), &len);
    CRegKey dev_key;
    dev_key.Open(sysenum_key, keypath.GetBuffer(), KEY_READ);
    len = max_len;
    dev_key.QueryStringValue(_T("FriendlyName"), friendlyname.GetBuffer(), &len);
    CRegKey devparams_key;
    devparams_key.Open(dev_key, _T("Device Parameters"), KEY_READ);
    len = max_len;
    devparams_key.QueryStringValue(_T("PortName"), portname.GetBuffer(), &len);
    ATLTRACE(friendlyname);
    ATLTRACE(portname);
    CString newname;
    newname.Format(_T("COM%d"), 50);
    ATLTRACE(newname);
    friendlyname.Replace(portname, newname);
    ATLTRACE(friendlyname);

    devparams_key.Close();
    dev_key.Close();
}
sysenum_key.Close();
serenum_key.Close();
}
```

the traces I'm getting show what I expect to see coming from the registry key, and the new name, but the friendly name remains unchanged:

```
Communications Port (COM1)
COM1
COM50
Communications Port (COM1)
```

why does `Replace` work in the first instance but not with the registry key values?
for note I'm working with visual studio community 2017, platform toolset v141, Unicode, x64

Comment: Try to step into MFC's `Replace` method. You'll see what happens.

Comment: still getting to grips with using a debugger, tried that and found that it was not able to see the new or old strings for replacement, I tried changing them to use `GetBuffer()` on those two arguments which replaced something, but unfortunately with gibberish.

Comment: You are missing `CString::ReleaseBuffer()` calls, so the string length won't be set to the actual length of the strings read from the registry.

Comment: thank you. this was the hint I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on [CString::GetBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getbuffer) explains, how to use this class member:

> If you use the pointer returned by `GetBuffer` to change the string contents, **you must call [ReleaseBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#releasebuffer) before you use any other `CSimpleStringT` member methods**.

If you don't, the internal state of the `CString` object is not valid. The `GetBuffer`/`ReleaseBuffer` family of class members are useful, when you need to attach non-`CString` string data to `CString` instances. The former temporarily disable class invariants, where the latter re-establishes them, so they always need to be called in tandem.